# USB authentication

Tags: 18.04, usb, authentication

This might be a wierd question and i'm sorry if this is wrong place to ask.

So, I have a sorts of assignment from my college to make automatic USB authentication work on a system. I was given "pam usb" as a program to work with. Now, i must say this is first time i ever work in Ubuntu so i literally have no idea what im doing.

After tearing through lots of errors and problems during installation i was finally able to compile pam usb, however now i've encountered a problem that i can't find a solution to. After typing **sudo pamusb-conf --add-device device** this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pamusb-conf", line 252, in <module>
    '/org/freedesktop/UDisks')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UDisks was not provided by any .service files
```

After looking for some info it seems that pam usb was abandoned long time ago. Is there nothing that can be done about this error? And if so, is there anything similar to pam usb that can help me to create an USB auth on a system?

EDIT:

lsb output as requested:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `lsb_release -a` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek done!